# OO design in python. Up across and down?

Tags: python, oop, composition

My question is really about how two objects that have both been created by a parent class can talk to each other. The real use case I have is for a PySide GUI application where two widgets that are sitting on a CentralWidget need to connect a signal and slot.

However the problem is more generic than that so I have a silly example to demonstrate the problem.

In particular is the "asksister" method in Son, where I know that the parent has a daughter and I need to connect those two methods. However, by hard linking the connection, means I can't run unittests without creating the entire object structure.

Is there a better way?

Would it be just less lame if I posted my real code here (after simplifying)

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.son = Son(self)
        self.daughter = Daughter(self)
        self.son.dohomework()


class Son(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def dohomework(self):
        print 'The answer is {0}'.format(self.asksister())

    def asksister(self):
        return self.parent.daughter.answer()


class Daughter(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def answer(self):
        return 42

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent = Parent()
```

Comment: In your real use case, could you hook up the signal and the slot in the part of code that creates the two widgets?

Answer (score 3):

I think that it is difficult to answer conclusively with a generic example such as the one you present. The point is that these two objects must interact, and their layout and communication depends on the domain and the entities they represent. Different design strategies may be equally valid, one fitting better than another for a specific case.

If it was on me, I would register the sister and the brother, leaving the parent out of the communication, but again, this is one design. If sister and brother were a view and a model, and the parent a controller, I would instead have them both talk only to the controller.

Another alternative would be to have Son request a helpService, where the sister previously registered as helpProvider. This way, the son must know the helpService, and gets the sister indirectly.

Comment: @op : you may want to have a look at the "mediator" design pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I now understand why the premise of my question is somewhat flawed, there is no right answer as such. More to the point, my design is poor and I need to look a little more carefully at finding a design pattern that is appropriate to my use case.